# findViewById() returns null when accessing custom view

Tags: android, view

I created a custom view which inherits from `android.view.View;` and added this view to the activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="...MainActivity">

    <view
        android:id="@+id/doorView"
        class="CustomView"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="220dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/..."/>
    </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Problem: `findViewById` always returns `null`. `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);` is called before.

```
doorView = (DoorView) this.findViewById(R.id.doorView);
```

EDIT: Constructor of `DoorView`:

```
public DoorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: The ids don't match but that's probably just an edit in the question you posted. Post your custom view constructors.

Comment: @laalto I did so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the `AttributeSet` to the super constructor.

Change

```
public DoorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context);
}
```

to

```
public DoorView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
}
```

Otherwise the attributes read by the superclasses such as `android:id` don't get set.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have `doorView` id, you have `customView`.

You need to use `R.id.customView`